# Problem In Restore Database In C#

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, database, database-restore

I define every thing Already and this code is a part of my code

```
if (Sql_Conn == null)
    Sql_Conn = new SqlConnection(Str_Con);
// str_con is my connection string

if (Sql_Conn.State != ConnectionState.Open)
   Sql_Conn.Open();

Data_Table = new DataTable();
DataA_dapter = new SqlDataAdapter();

Sql_Cmd = new SqlCommand();
Sql_Cmd.Connection = Sql_Conn; // 

string sql = "RESTORE DATABASE  [" + str_directory + "] From DISK = " +
                        "'" + strFileName + "' ; ";
// str_directory is the source of my database as DB.MDF
// srtFileName is the directory of DB.bak
Sql_Cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
Sql_Cmd.CommandText = sql;

try
{
    Sql_Cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
catch (SqlException Error_Exception)
{
   MessageBox.Show("Error");
}
```

When I use `string sql` in SQL Sserver with new query I don't have problem and my database restores successfully but when I use this code with c# I see this error

> Error : {System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: RESTORE cannot
>   process database 'E:/DB.mdf' because it is in use by this session. It
>   is recommended that the master database be used when performing this
>   operation. RESTORE DATABASE is terminating abnormally.

I want to restore my database. I have to open connection at the first of my codes and when I want to restore my database I see Exception.

Now how can I restore my database?  Please Help Me.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to restore SQL Server database through C# code](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4218960/how-to-restore-sql-server-database-through-c-code)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the connection string. If it contains an Initial Catalog setting set it to Master.

Comment: Thank you . but how can i open master database and what is connection string for this database. i do this but i see this error : >An attempt to attach an auto-named database for file master.mdf failed. A database with the same name exists, or specified file cannot be opened, or it is located on UNC share

Comment: @Masoud Abasian, could you show your connection string (without password!)?

Answer (score 5):

You can't restore the exact database that you have connected to. As the error message mentions, you should use the `master` database instead.

In your connections string use `database=master`.

Answer (score 3):

You need to be connected to a different database than the one you are trying to restore.  Set a different database (inital catalog) in you connection string, connect, then run the code.

[See how to restore sql-server database Through C# code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4218960/how-to-restore-sql-server-database-through-c-code) for the same problem.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you connection string is being initialized with Initial Catalog (or Database) set to the database that you want to restore. This causes a connection to be active (you can check this by executing sp_who2 system stored procedure) thus prohibiting you to do restore. You should set your Initial Catalog (or Database) value in a connection string to master database. This should leave your target database free from connections and will allow you to do the restore process.

Comment: Thank you . but how can i open master database and what is connection string for this database. i do this but i see this error : >An attempt to attach an auto-named database for file master.mdf failed. A database with the same name exists, or specified file cannot be opened, or it is located on UNC share

Comment: You connection string should be something like this <add name="MyCS" connectionString="Data Source=YOUR_SERVER;Initial Catalog=master;Integrated Security=True;" (or if you are using SQL Server authentication replace Integrated Security=True with User ID=your_user_id;Password=your_password;" />