# C# Attach or restore Database after installation finish

Tags: c#, wpf, sql-server-2008

I am new to the wpf.

I have WPF application. Now i want to attach or restore my database to sql server 2008 after finishing my installation of my application.

How to do that?

Do i have to put mdf/ldf file or BAK file in project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How to restore SQL Server database through C# code:
[How to restore SQL Server database through C# code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4218960/how-to-restore-sql-server-database-through-c-sharp-code)

Programmatically Enumerating, Attaching, and Detaching SQL Server Databases
http://justlikeamagic.com/2010/04/13/programmatically-enumerating-attaching-and-detaching-sql-server-databases/