# Deploy An Application with database

Tags: c#, deployment

I have Created an application in C# and used SQL server 2012 for database. I have made the setup file for the app as well. Now I want to Install the App on the target machine.How to go? Where will i have to place the database and how to pick database from my machine? Note:I don't want to create a new database on target machine.Please Help

Comment: **1)** Install .Net **2)** Install SqlServer **3)** Restore the backup of your database **3)** (bind the front-end to back-end: in design-time) and run the project

Comment: Thanks @Mehdi, :( but to which directory restore the backup of db?

Comment: you can simply put the backup file in project resource or same directory of project.

Comment: Do you want to I put a complete answer?? @Khan

Comment: It will be great if you can :) @Mehdi

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To deploy a C# application, follow the instruction below

1. install .Net Framework
2. Install the Sql Server
3. Restore the Database , [How to restore SQL Server database through C# code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4218960/how-to-restore-sql-server-database-through-c-sharp-code)
4. Run the project